# How to replace Rails' Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I'm storing the *Rails Sessions* in database using *Active Record Store*. At some point I want to replace the actual *Rails Session* for another one extracted from the database.

Let's say the *Session to restore* ID comes in the param `session_id`.

How can I retrieve the Session to restore and replace the actual session?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found to do it is in a before_filter

```
def restore_session
  return if params[:session_id].blank?

  restored_session = ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.find_by_session_id(params[:session_id])
  if restored_session
    session.update(restored_session.data)
    restored_session.destroy
  end
end
```